# KML in leaflet angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, maps, leaflet

I am using angular leaflet directive from [tombatossals](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive)

First of all thank you tombatossals for creating such a extensive directive that works awesome with leaflet..

**Question**

1) Anyone has used used KML with this directive  or Does this lib support KML ?

Answer (score 0):

The leaflet-angular directives do not support kml. You will need a Leaflet plugin such as [this](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/layer/vector/KML.js) to get this functionality and interact directly with the map object:

`leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) { 
     //add L.KML from plugin to map
});`

[example of accessing map object](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/examples/access-leaflet-object-example.html)